# Asserting a drop down menu in selenium IDE

Tags: php, html, selenium, drop-down-menu, assert

so I am Using `Selenium IDE` and I must assert that the field is a drop down menu, which commands can I use?

*This is what I have tried till now with no success:*

```
Command: assertSelectedValue
select: *name of drop down* 
value: ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *assertValue()*.

Page:

```
<select name="select_example">
  <option value="my_1">text1</option>
  <option value="my_2">text2</option>
</select>
```

Command:

```
Command: assertValue
Target: name=select_example
Value: my_1
```